# Create custom metadata Tags for documents to be uploaded in Alfresco

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I am exploring with **alfresco 4.3 & 5.0**,

As we know our normal documents have metadata properties like *Author,Title,Subject,Category*.... & so on.

So if it has some values, alfresco retrieves data values from these & displays in that file **properties** section like :Name,Title,Author,size,creator......and many more.

So Suppose If I have a some more form fields in my document (like firstName,Tenant,isAuthrorized), then what are the all steps that I need to follow in alfresco so that whenever user will upload any document , under that file properties section, all the properties will get displayed and also If I will select edit properties option, I should be able to edit them.

I have followed this pdf :http://ecmarchitect.com/images/articles/alfresco-content/content-article...

By using which I am able to see new drop-down values under create rule section.

Similar way I want to do it document properties section, so that similar to existing properties like Name, Title,Description,MimeType,Tags... etc , I can also see my new properties like firstName,Tenant - all are text fields.

Please show me the way to achieve these things for Alfresco 5.0 a community . To achieve this do I need to import Alfresco sdk, or can I directly changes in tomcat?

Also one more question, I want to create a custom metadata in alfresco , so that if excel sheet(column)have values ,then all such properties with their values should be displayed under properties section of that file.

Is it possible in alfresco?

If yes can you provide me some way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can create custom metadata in alfresco.For that in alfresco you can use alfresco content model.For reference you can study below link of alfresco.

https://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Data_Dictionary_Guide

Below are some basic information.

You will need to create 2 files for creating custom metadata.
**1. Context file**
**2. Model file**

Both files will be inside *alfresco/extension* folder.

There is one another approach for dynamic model creation.For that you only need to create one file which you will need to upload inside **"/Data Dictionary/Models"**

Comment: Hey @Krutik Thanks for quick reply.Do we have any example available on net, which I can refer and test it. I tried to use this link http://blogs.alfresco.com/wp/wabson/2010/02/25/adding-custom-aspect-support-in-alfresco-share/, added all required changes directly in tomcat, but don't know how to test it.

Comment: The link you are prefering is used has only aspect.Belwo link has some more information on custom content model.https://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Step-By-Step:_Creating_A_Custom_Model

Comment: Once we added a new metatadata in our tomcat, how can we test that Alfresco is able to display it,I tried to test it by uploading a doc,containing fields word, but didn't see anything in alfresco properties file.